# Which is more true about learning?

Tags: perception, learning, cognition

I think / guess using multiple sources for education / learning is much better than using one source; I mean by source, visual, auditory, etc...
So at best I could learn from a person face-to-face, then watching some video, then reading a tutorial with graphs, etc...

but what about keeping reading and accumulating knowledge by forcing info by the act of just reading here and there, until the piece of info "clicks".. is that a good thing? What is bad about this method? what is good? It seems like to be clutter compared to the way of learning mentioned above this paragraph...

Comment: I think you might be wondering about elaborative encoding and experiential learning as opposed to more didactic